# ¿Cómo puedo subir imágenes desde el chat móvil?

Tags: soporte, chat, imágenes

Le he dado vueltas al sitio de chat movil y no he podido subir imagenes al chat en la aplicación móvil, si bien sé que puedo cambiar a la versión de escritorio y subirla, pero es más incómodo en un teléfono de pantalla pequeña.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se pueden subir imágenes desde el chat móvil por ahora.  La única manera es de subir la imagen al sitio normal y copiar el URL y compartirlo en la sala de chat....lo se, no es una manera agradable de hacer las cosas.

Comment: quizá se podría hacer un feature-request?